# What decides what datatype that will be used to store the temporary value in?

Tags: c, math

This might be very basic but I got very curious what the reason is.

When dealing with different types of operations such as multiplication and division with data by different types (int, float etc) what decides which datatype that gets picked?

For example, if I do the following:

```
float a = 5 / 10;
```

I will get "0" as result since the 5 and the 10 are temporarily stored in an int where we do the division, and then we put it in a float. Right?

But if we instead do:

```
float a = (float)5 / 10;
```

We get 0.5 instead.

How does the decision making look when float is prefered over int in this case in C?

Comment: Please specify your programming language.

Comment: does it make any difference? in that case, how would it work in c?

Comment: @chikuba Yes, it *does* make a difference. Some languages -- just as the *very popular* JavaScript -- do not have "integers", for instance (in JS the result of `5/10` is `0.5`). Please update the post/title accordingly; the -1 is for such a vague abstract question that cannot be answered with more details.

Comment: @chikuba "How does the decision making look when float is prefered over int in this case in C" C has a spec, and the spec determines what the type of each expression is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet.

```
float a = 5 / 10;
```

`5` and `10` are represented as integers to C (and Java and C++ and Python 2.x) by default.  They're not specified to be stored in any other way; that is to say, they don't match the appearance of a floating-point type.  Integer division results in truncation, so you'll get the value 0 every time.

Now, regarding the second snippet:

```
float a = (float)5 / 10;
```

...C (or Java or C++ or Python 2.x) will interpret it as:

```
float a = 5.0 / 10;
```

Because the floating-point value is of a higher rank than an integer, it will promote the integer to a float. This is known as type promotion.  You can read a bit about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Answer (score 2):

Different languages handle this differently; the specific rules regarding *[type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)* are part of the language specification.

The rules for C are described in the ANSI specification, and more conveniently here:
http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html

Answer (score 1):

Compilers usually don't try to "get what you mean", because it's impossible for them to get it right every single time.

They just do what you tell them, following a strict set of rules.

Here, the rule is: Dividing an integer by another integer returns an integer. Hence if you want floating-point division, just divide floating-point numbers.