# For what reason printf does not correctly display the float?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, printf

I hoped that in all cases showed `2.33`, however, for what reason only in the second case this happened?

```
printf("Without cast: %0.2f\n", 7 / 3); // Whitout cast: 0.00
printf("With cast: %0.2f\n", (float) 7 / 3); // With cast: 2.33
float x = 7 / 3;
printf("With var: %0.2f\n", x); // With var: 2.00
```

I just noticed this behavior with float. If I use an integer variable, it does not happen.

Comment: It is because `7` and `3`  are `int` type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What decides what datatype that will be used to store the temporary value in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221437/what-decides-what-datatype-that-will-be-used-to-store-the-temporary-value-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`7 / 3` without a cast is integer division, resulting in the integer 2, since any remainder is discarded, so it is equivalent of calling `printf("%0.2f\n", 2);`

Now, why does that print 0 instead of 2? Well, you told it it is a float in the format string ("%0.2**f**"). So it is interpreting your integer (0b0...000000000000010) as a float. And a float that has those bits set evaluates to zero, on a precision of `%0.2f`

Your compiler should have given you a warning that the format specifier doesn't match the passed type. **Don't ignore compiler warnings!**

With a cast it is different, since the cast has priority, so `(float) 7 / 3` is same as `7.0f / 3`, which is floating point division. With a variable, you did integer division, so ended up with a 2, but that two got cast into a float, so printf interpreted it correctly.